# Error whilst creating spectral graph on composite image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to create a spectral graph (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/charts_image_regions)based off a composite image. When i use this code, multiple errors come up, that all end with pattern pixel_qa not not match any bands.

Does someone know how to overcome this issue?

Here is the link to the map
https://code.earthengine.google.com/e4e45f74b30028629cdbb6c95f0da9de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply the cloud mask, it looks for `pixel_qa` band, that holds the cloud mask. If you select just some bands:

```js
var sr14= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
.filterBounds(point)
.filterDate('2002-05-15','2002-11-30')
.select(['B[1-5]']);  // Here you are selection bands from 1 to 5
```

you lose that information, and that is why the cloud mask doesn't work. You have 2 options:

1. just comment that line and leave all bands
2. include `pixel_qa` in the selection